# Как удалить название колонки, когда используешь value_counts() в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Как удалить название колонки, когда используешь value_counts() в pandas?

```
df[['id']].value_counts()
```

выдает:

```
id        
7313055922    2
7315995136    2
7311721201    2
7316417087    2
7316803329    2
             ..
7310104567    1
7310104655    1
7310105071    1
7310105763    1
7317090004    1
Length: 10000, dtype: int64
```

хочу видеть:

```
7313055922    2
7315995136    2
7311721201    2
7316417087    2
7316803329    2
             ..
7310104567    1
7310104655    1
7310105071    1
7310105763    1
7317090004    1
Length: 10000, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Совершенно непонятно, зачем, но можно так, например:

```
print(df["id"].value_counts().to_string(header=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно удалить имя индекса, присвоив ему `None`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.random.randint(100,110,100)})
vc = df['id'].value_counts()
vc.index.name = None
print(vc)
```

```
103    14
101    13
102    12
106    11
104    11
109     8
105     8
107     8
108     8
100     7
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

В вашем случае из-за конструкции `df[['id']]` формируется не просто индекс, а мультииндекс, поэтому можно сделать так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.random.randint(100,110,100)})
vc = df[['id']].value_counts()
vc.index.names = [None]
print(vc)
```